# Get attribute value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, youtube

I need to get attribute value in the below code

```
<div objecttag="" id="data_url" class="new_data ng-scope" dataurl="http://www.youtube.com/v/uPiVOofEPHM?version=3&amp;f=playlists&amp;c=youtube_it&amp;app=youtube_gdata"><object objecttag="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/uPiVOofEPHM?version=3&amp;f=playlists&amp;c=youtube_it&amp;app=youtube_gdata?wmode=transparent&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;fs=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;version=3&amp;allowScriptAccess=always&amp;allowFullScreen=true" width="898" height="505" id="player" style="visibility: visible;"></object></div>
```

Im using in below jquery code

```
 data_url = $("#data_url").attr('dataurl');
             alert(data_url);
```

Its not getting attribute value in chrome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GzKv7/1/ ... make sure you are running the code under dom ready handler

Answer (score 1):

Wrap you code in [DOM raedy](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Try [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(function(){
    data_url = $("#data_url").prop('dataurl');
                 alert(data_url);
});
```

or
[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

change HTML

```
<div objecttag="" id="data_url" data-url="">
```

**js**

```
$(function(){
data_url = $("#data_url").data('url');
 alert(data_url);
});
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1):

Try to write your code in [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) like,

```
$(function(){
    data_url = $("#data_url").attr('dataurl');
    alert(data_url);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PNhn3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function myFunction() {

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("dataurl"); 
alert(x);}
```